# MutableStateOf work with sharedPreferences

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, android-jetpack-compose

I want to set the sharedPreferences value to the MutableStateOf, but it report

> Type 'MutableState<TypeVariable(T)>' has no method 'getValue(MainViewModel, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate

seem like MutableStateOf can not work with sharedPreferences.

```
// viewModel
// ...
    var item: String by mutableStateOf(appPreferences.getItemName())
        private set
// ...

// sharedPreferences
    private val prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
    fun getItemName(): String {
        return prefs.getString(PREF_ITEM_NAME, "")!!
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The android studio hint I can import below two package to remove this error.

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
```